# Knowing whether to output terminal escape sequences?

Tags: c, terminal, pipe, tty

I have a C program that uses [SGR ("Select Graphic Rendition")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) ANSI terminal escape sequences to produce color output.

However, if output is being redirected to a text file, then the escape sequences should *not* be output since they'd be seen as "garbage" in the generated file. To handle this, one can use the **isatty**(3) function: output color *only if* it returns `true`. Indeed, this is what programs like **grep**(1) do.

But if output is being being redirected to a Unix pipe, e.g., `| less` that, at least in my case, is primarily what someone would pipe the output of my program to, then the escape sequences *should* be output since **less**(1) correctly handles them and prints in color.

After some testing using **isatty**(3) and **fstat**(3), I've produced this table where `C` represents my C program, the "Should?" column is whether I should output color, and the remaining columns are T/F as the return value of **isatty** or **fstat**(`STDOUT_FILENO`):

```
COMMAND  Should? isatty ISCHR ISFIFO ISREG
======== ======= ====== ===== ====== =====
C          T      T      T     F      F
C > file   F      F      F     F    >>T<<---- The interesting case.
C | less   T      F      F     T      F
```

Hence, it would seem that I want to output color *except* when `ISREG` on the `stat` struct on stdout is T.

Are there any caveats with doing this? If there are, is there a better way to get what I want?

**Note**: I *also* have an option similar to **grep**'s `--color` option to specify either `auto` or `always` (or `none` simply by *not* specifying any option at all). My hope in using **fstat** and `ISREG` is to make the `auto` case better the majority of the time.

Comment: You should also include a command line flag so the user can override, similar to gnu grep's --color flag.

Comment: Try `yourprogram | cat > file`.

Comment: Actually, I do have such a command line option. I'm just trying to make the "auto" setting better.

Comment: The pipe to cat seems contrived. Why would anyone actually do that?

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas: They probably wouldn't, but they might well do something like `yourprogram | grep > file`

Comment: In cases like this, it's preferable to the user to have unambiguous behavior, even if that requires a command-line option to obtain the result.

Comment: The behavior _is_ unambiguous: do color if `ISREG` on the stat of stdout is false. Grep's "auto" behavior, although different, is also unambiguous: do color if **isatty** on stdout is true.

Comment: The grep behaviouris there for a reason. Perhaps, given its ubiquity, it would be wise to just follow suit.

Comment: Actually, I also asked on the grep mailing list. The reasons are (1) at least in the case of grep, the user is more likely to chain greps; and (2) it's historical. So far, I've not heard any _technical_ caveats. My program can supply _both_ options, actually.